# Coordinate converter in R (GPS, DMS, dd, etc.)

Tags: coordinate-system, r, gps

There is probably a way to do this, but I can't find a way to transform a GPS DMS format to degree decimal in R.

e.g. from GPS coordinate, see below, is there a way to transform this in R?

```
gps.coord <- "S0 44.437 W90 18.131"
```

The format is `GPS: [N,S] dd mm.mmm [W,E] dd mm.mmm`

This is the way I made it! (There is probably a better way)

```
lat = - as.numeric(substr(gsub(pattern = "S0 ",
                               replacement = "",gps.coord),
                          start = 0,stop = 6))/60
lat.dd = lat - as.numeric(substr(gps.coord,2,3))
lon = - as.numeric(substr(gsub(pattern = "S0 ",
                               replacement = "",
                               gps.coord),
                          start = 12,stop = 18))/60
lon.dd = lon - as.numeric(substr(gps.coord,12,13))
```

**Decimal Degrees (WGS84)**

```
Latitude    Longitude
-0.740617   -90.302183
```

**Degrees, Minutes & Seconds**

```
Latitude    Longitude
S0 44 26    W90 18 07
```

**GPS**

```
Latitude    Longitude
S 0 44.437  W 90 18.131
```

**UTM**

```
X   Y
15S 800286  9918048
```

I'm looking for something [like this site](http://boulter.com/gps/?c=S0%2044.437%20W90%2018.131#S0%2044.437%20W90%2018.131) where from one input, you get different possible output.

Comment: In your case is string work; you have to either divide the latter part by 60, extracting the minute part using str_split; for western longitudes you must use -abs(), that's the way spatial packages understand west; there's the function sp::char2dms() %>% sp::as.numericDMS() which takes a string in the format degrees minutes seconds with separators, which would require you to convert the latter part to seconds and then put separators between numbers.

Comment: Converting decimal degrees to decimal minutes or degrees-minutes-seconds is basic algebra. Adding in the UTM changes this into multiple questions (and failure to specify which zone makes this 60 locations).